# CPLEX and PYTHONPATH

Tags: bash, python-2.7, paths

First I installed CPLEX on my ubuntu. Then I set my `PYTHONPATH` by adding the following line to `.bashrc` file

```
export PYTHONPATH="/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/python/2.7/x86-64_linux"
```

but when I'm writing

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

it's empty :(

Answer (score 2):

Before the change you made to `.bashrc` file can take effect, you need to restart your shell by running the following command in the terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Closing all open terminals and opening a new terminal does the same thing as the above command.